# Print list of all error messages after running an R script

Tags: r, error-handling

Apologies if there is an obvious answer to this question, but I haven't found one.

All I'm looking for is the error equivalent of `warnings()` - I want to run a script, then get a list of all the errors that occurred when running the script.

Have had a look at `traceback()` and it seems like it might do what I want - the help file says *"The default display is of the stack of the last uncaught error"* - but can't figure out how to make it return all uncaught errors rather than just the last one.

Comment: R stops running the code as soon as it encounters an error. To avoid this you might try making a function that runs every line with `tryCatch()` and captures any resulting errors.

Comment: Thanks @CephBirk. the individual function containing the error may stop running but the rest of my script continues. I have a very long script and I don't want to have to scroll all the way back up through the console to see if there were any errors... so after something analogous to warnings() that I can run at the end to provide this info for me.

Comment: The rest of the script only continues when you are in interactive mode. My suggestion would be, save the script (`script.R`) then run the whole script using `source('script.R')`. This will stop at every error. If you just want to see if errors exist, this will be a good way to do it.

Comment: That answers my question thank you @CephBirk. If you want to write this up as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be, save the script (e.g. `script.R`) then run the whole script using `source('script.R')`. This will stop at every error. If you just want to see if errors exist, this will be a good way to do it.